# powershell Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility module could not be loaded

Tags: powershell

I have this problem in a brand new workstation with Windows 10 installed: on powershell, the 5.1, when I call "Write-Host 'test'" I receive

```
Write-Host : The 'Write-Host' command was found in the module 
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility', but the module could not
be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'.
At line:1 char:1

+ Write-Host "test"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

And if I try to Import-Module I receive an error.
I installed the powershell 7.2 and in that case I have no problem, but I must use the 5.1 for compatibility reasons.
I already tried to remove/reinstall the powershell windows feature but no way.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thx

Comment: "And if I try to Import-Module I receive an error" - show us that error :)

Comment: on my install [win10pro, ps5.1], the module is located at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` and that is on the `$env:PSModulePath`. have you checked your setup for that yet?

Comment: Hi, the module path is correct ( "PS C:\Windows\system32> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\aiteam\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\" ) and I even have the Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility in there. However I get the error "Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility, Version=3.0.0.0"